# JS Game Results Not What I Expect

Tags: javascript, html

I'm fairly new to JS and I'm currently trying to make my first simple game. The premise is that the player must choose and submit a bet. They then chose one of three cups and win if the ball is in the chosen cup.
It's mostly functioning as I hoped to except the outcome for how much money they gain.
The player starts with $40 and when its a loss it correctly subtracts the bet amount. When the player wins however it does not add the bet amount but instead puts it beside the previous amount.
For example, if the player has $40 and bets $5 and wins it will change their total to $405.
I have noticed that this does not happen for the first bet if the player wins but then does not work again on subsequent guesses.
I can not figure what is causing this behavior and any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Hobo Balls</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="hobo.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Hobo Balls</h1>
    <h2>Instructions</h2>
  </div>
    <div class="cups">
      <div id="cup1-image">
        <img src="/Cup1.png">
      </div>
      <div id="cup2-image">
        <img src="/Cup2.png">
      </div>
      <div id="cup3-image">
        <img src="/Cup3.png">
      </div>
    </div>  
    <br>
  <div>
    <label for="bet">Place Your Bet</label>
    <input name="bet" id="bet" type="number" min="1" max="400" value="0"/>
    <input id="enter-bet" type="submit"/>
    <p id="show-bet"></p>
  </div> 
  <div class="result">
    <h3>You are a ???</h3>
    <p id="win-or-lose"></p>
  </div>
  <p id="cash"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/hoboscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
let cup1;
let cup2;
let cup3;

let playerGuess;
let playerBet;
let playerCash = 40;
let outcome;



//Player enters bet amount
document.getElementById("enter-bet").addEventListener("click", function () {
    playerBet = document.getElementById("bet").value;
    document.getElementById("show-bet").innerHTML = "You bet $" + playerBet;
});

//Determine ball position
const ballPlacement = () => {
  const ballResult = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  console.log(ballResult);
  if (ballResult === 0) {
    cup1 = 'ball';
    cup2 = 'crab';
    cup3 = 'hobo';
  } else if (ballResult === 1) {
    cup1 = 'crab';
    cup2 = 'ball';
    cup3 = 'hobo';
  } else { (ballResult === 2); {
    cup1 = 'hobo';
    cup2 = 'crab';
    cup3 = 'ball';
  }
  }
};

//Determine if guess iscorrect and display result
const playerWin = () => {
  //correct Guess
    if (playerGuess === 'cup1' && cup1 === 'ball') {
        outcome = 'win'; document.querySelector("h3").innerHTML = "You are a Winner"; document.getElementById('cup1-image').innerHTML = '<img src="/ball.jpg">';
    } else if (playerGuess === 'cup2' && cup2 === 'ball') {
        outcome = 'win'; document.querySelector("h3").innerHTML = "You are a Winner"; document.getElementById('cup2-image').innerHTML = '<img src="/ball.jpg">';
    } else if (playerGuess === 'cup3' && cup3 === 'ball') {
        outcome = 'win'; document.querySelector("h3").innerHTML = "You are a Winner"; document.getElementById('cup3-image').innerHTML = '<img src="/ball.jpg">';
   //incorrect guess
    } else if (playerGuess === 'cup1' && cup1 === 'crab') { 
        outcome = 'lose'; document.querySelector("h3").innerHTML = "You are a Loser"; document.getElementById('cup1-image').innerHTML = '<img src="/crab.jpg">';
    } else if (playerGuess === 'cup1' && cup1 === 'hobo') {
        outcome = 'lose'; document.querySelector("h3").innerHTML = "You are a Loser"; document.getElementById('cup1-image').innerHTML = '<img src="/hobo.jpg">';
    } else if (playerGuess === 'cup2' && cup2 === 'crab') { 
        outcome = 'lose'; document.querySelector("h3").innerHTML = "You are a Loser"; document.getElementById('cup2-image').innerHTML = '<img src="/crab.jpg">';
    } else if (playerGuess === 'cup2' && cup2 === 'hobo') {
        outcome = 'lose'; document.querySelector("h3").innerHTML = "You are a Loser"; document.getElementById('cup2-image').innerHTML = '<img src="/hobo.jpg">'; 
    } else if (playerGuess === 'cup3' && cup3 === 'crab') { 
        outcome = 'lose'; document.querySelector("h3").innerHTML = "You are a Loser"; document.getElementById('cup3-image').innerHTML = '<img src="/crab.jpg">';
    } else if (playerGuess === 'cup3' && cup3 === 'hobo') {
        outcome = 'lose'; document.querySelector("h3").innerHTML = "You are a Loser"; document.getElementById('cup3-image').innerHTML = '<img src="/hobo.jpg">';
    }
};

//Player selects cup, previous functions are called
document.getElementById("cup1-image").addEventListener("click", function () {
  playerGuess = 'cup1';
  ballPlacement();
  playerWin();
  if (outcome === 'win') {
    playerCash = playerCash + playerBet;
 } else if (outcome === 'lose') {
   playerCash = playerCash - playerBet;
 }
  document.getElementById('win-or-lose').innerHTML = outcome;
  document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML = "You have $" + playerCash + " remaining";
});

document.getElementById("cup2-image").addEventListener("click", function () {
  playerGuess = 'cup2';
  ballPlacement();
  playerWin();
  if (outcome === 'win') {
    playerCash = playerCash + playerBet;
 } else if (outcome === 'lose') {
   playerCash = playerCash - playerBet;
 }
  document.getElementById('win-or-lose').innerHTML = outcome;
  document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML = "You have $" + playerCash + " remaining";
});

document.getElementById("cup3-image").addEventListener("click", function () {
  playerGuess = 'cup3';
  ballPlacement();
  playerWin();
  if (outcome === 'win') {
    playerCash = playerCash + playerBet;
 } else if (outcome === 'lose') {
   playerCash = playerCash - playerBet;
 }
  document.getElementById('win-or-lose').innerHTML = outcome;
  document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML = "You have $" + playerCash + " remaining";
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here in your code:

```
document.getElementById("enter-bet").addEventListener("click", function () {
    playerBet = document.getElementById("bet").value;
    document.getElementById("show-bet").innerHTML = "You bet $" + playerBet;
});
```

The variable `playerBet` is being assigned a string value, change the statement to:

```js
  playerBet = parseInt(document.getElementById("bet").value;
```

Comment: You are Amazing! thank you so much this has solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use `valueAsNumber` instead of `value` for number inputs:

```js
//Player enters bet amount
document.getElementById("enter-bet").addEventListener("click", function () {
    playerBet = document.getElementById("bet").valueAsNumber;
    document.getElementById("show-bet").innerHTML = "You bet $" + playerBet;
})
```

Comment: I did not know that, ty!